# Netty 4 PooledByteBufAllocator returns incorrect information about allocations/deallocations

Tags: netty

The following test outputs numbers from PooledByteBufAllocator arenas, and when I run it the numbers don't match the actual allocations/deallocations.
Actual allocations: 50000
Actual deallocations: 50000
Active buffers: 0

the output shows the following:
directActive 1 directAlloc 1 directDealloc 0
heapActive 0 heapAlloc 0 heapDealloc 0

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.PoolArenaMetric;
import io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator;
import io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector;
import io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.Level;

import org.junit.Test;

public class NettyTest2 {
    public static PooledByteBufAllocator alloc = new PooledByteBufAllocator(true); 

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(Level.PARANOID);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            ByteBuf b = alloc.buffer(1000, 1000);
            b.release();
        }

        Thread.sleep(100);

        //alloc.freeThreadLocalCache();

        showActiveDirectBuffers();
        showActiveHeapBuffers();
    }

    void showActiveDirectBuffers() {
        int directActive = 0, directAlloc = 0, directDealloc = 0;
        for (PoolArenaMetric arena : alloc.directArenas()) {
            directActive += arena.numActiveAllocations();
            directAlloc += arena.numAllocations();
            directDealloc += arena.numDeallocations();
        }
        System.out.println("directActive " + directActive + " directAlloc " + directAlloc + " directDealloc " + directDealloc);
    }

    void showActiveHeapBuffers() {
        int heapActive = 0, heapAlloc = 0, heapDealloc = 0;
        for (PoolArenaMetric arena : alloc.heapArenas()) {
            heapActive += arena.numActiveAllocations();
            heapAlloc += arena.numAllocations();
            heapDealloc += arena.numDeallocations();
        }
        System.out.println("heapActive " + heapActive + " heapAlloc " + heapAlloc + " heapDealloc " + heapDealloc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is connected to internal cache of Allocators.
Allocator with disabled cache shows alloc/dealloc numbers matching the actual calls.

To create a PooledBufferAllocator with disabled cache use the following way (as it was suggested in https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/5275)

```
PooledByteBufAllocator alloc = new PooledByteBufAllocator(true, 1, 1, 8192, 11, 0, 0, 0);
```